# increment progress bar depending on counter

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

How can I get the progress bar to change 'speed' or setInterval depending on the counter value? So for instance if the bar is less than 40 - do this, or less than 60 do that, and so on.

I'm trying to slow down the progress bar after it gets to 40, and then furthermore at 60 percent.

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (counter <= '40') {
            progressLoading.val(counter);
            counter = counter += 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 20);
```

Comment: add, let's say `0.2` to counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in the console and see if this is the effect you want.

```
var counter = 0;
var factor = 1;

var damping = 80; // Increase this to slow down increment.

// This is the minimum value of 'factor'. Increasing this will speed up the function
var minVal = 0.1; 

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(Math.ceil(counter)); // Call your function here.
    counter = counter + factor;
    if (counter > 40 && counter < 100) {
        factor = Math.max((100 - counter)/damping, minVal)
    } else if (counter > 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 20);
```

Initially, `counter` is being incremented by `factor = 1`. After `40`, the `factor` is gradually reduced. The minimum value of `factor` cannot be less than `minVal`.

Showing progress with more irregularity -

```
var counter = 0;
var factor = 1;

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(Math.ceil(counter)); // Call your function here.
    counter = counter + factor;
    if (counter > 40 && counter < 100) {
        factor = Math.max(Math.abs(Math.sin(100 - counter)), 0.1)
    } else if (counter > 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 20);
```

`Math.sin` function always returns a number between `-1` to `+1`. We need only positive, so we pass it through `Math.abs`. This makes `factor` to always be between `0` and `1`.

Also, the number might be way too small and hence the factor value maybe insignificant. To make sure this doesn't happen, we have set a minimum value as `0.1`, which is checked by `Math.max`.

Showing progress with irregularity and decreasing speed -

```
var counter = 0;
var factor = 1;

var maxVal = 1; // Maximum value of `factor` after crossing 40
var minVal = 0.1; // Minimum value of `maxVal`
var damping = 60; // damping for `maxVal`

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(Math.ceil(counter)); // Call your function here.
    counter = counter + factor;
    if (counter > 40 && counter < 100) {
        maxVal = Math.max((100 - counter)/damping, minVal)
        factor = Math.min(Math.max(Math.abs(Math.sin(100 - counter)), 0.1), maxVal);
    } else if (counter > 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 20);
```

This one is both of the above combined. In the second one, `factor` could be anything between `0` and `1`. The above function makes sure that `factor` is between `0` and `maxVal` and we keep decreasing `maxVal` from `1` to `0.1` using the damping function used in 1.

Comment: Great. Accept the answer if this is fitting.

Comment: Would there be a way to add some 'irregularity' to the damping - making it speed up and slow down, mimicking something similar to a true progress bar?

Comment: Try setting `0.1` to `0.05`, in the second snippet.

Comment: Are these not able to be used together so that the factor is still gradually reduced, but also have the irregularity?